# Запись данных в .csv

Tags: python, парсер, csv

Как записать значение в .csv что бы значение каждое значение было в своём столбце, при этом длина списков разная пример я прикрепляю в ссылке. Большое спасибо за ответы

Расскажу подробнее, собираю данные с сайта Икеи, и там в карточке товаров всегда разное количество характеристик, например: вес, длина и т.д, а мне надо записать всё в один файл, и что бы каждое значение было под своим именем

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uGoW1kpsDGDA-Zh7SiiCDcg9cf2lHQUd/view?usp=sharing

Если что-то не понятно, оставляёте комментарии, попробую рассказать ещё подробнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант, можно попробовать характеристики записать в словари, считать словари в DataFrame pandas, и из pandas выгрузить в csv.
что-то вроде этого:

```
import pandas as pd

products = [{'артикул': 12345, 'высота': 50, 'материал': 'дерево'},
            {'артикул': 12346, 'ширина': 30, 'вес':1.5}, 
            {'артикул': 12347, 'длина':14, 'высота': 6.2, 'материал': 'пластик'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['артикул', 'длина', 'ширина', 'высота', 'вес', 'материал'])

for p in products:
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(p,index=[0])],ignore_index=True)
    
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)

#
    артикул длина   ширина  высота  вес материал
0   12345   NaN     NaN     50      NaN дерево
1   12346   NaN     30      NaN     1.5 NaN
2   12347   14      NaN     6.2     NaN пластик
```

Comment: У меня запись происходит вот так 
''''
num = 0
for item in param:
        print(titles[num].text)
        content.append({titles[num].text:item.text})
        num+=1
'''
Скорее всего это не правильно, т.к на выходе я получаю _[{'Ширина:\xa0': '128 см'}, {'Глубина:\xa0': '58 см'}, {'Мин высота:\xa0': '59 см'}, {'Макс высота:\xa0': '72 см'}, {'Макс нагрузка:\xa0': '50 кг'} и из-за этого ломается структура файла

Comment: не очень понимаю что делает этот цикл (что за переменные и пр.) 'for item in param:'

Comment: не уверен, но возможно, надо что-то вроде этого: 'content = []
for i in items:
    content += [{titles[num].text:item.text for num, item in enumerate(param)}] '

Comment: Переменная titles это массив со всеми заголовками, а param со всеми параметрами, цикл добавляет пару ключ:значение в общий массив

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12Hx7LNcJKGA9iY-J29p2R8bz6L-Wk9cj?usp=sharing вот ссылка где хранятся код и результат который получился

Comment: а как в param отделяются параметры разных товаров? есть какой-то разделитель, ключ, или как?

Comment: Я с сайта достаю список параметров, их всегда столько же сколько и ключей, в рещультате получаю 2 массива param и titles

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128903/discussion-between---and-sergfsm).